# Must declare the scalar variable & Incorrect syntax near

Tags: sql-server

how to fix this problem
it was work but i add some new lines and change some then this error appear 
it was @Old_CH_SWORD_ID and i changed it to @Old_CH_HA_ID like codes down and same with all codes i change all 
and this the declare

```
 Declare @CreaterName Varchar(60) = 'iLegend' , -- Creater Name
 @WeaponSlot Int = 13 , -- char inventory weapon slot
 @ReqOptLevel Int = 7    , -- Change old item requiared plus for upgrade.
 @NewOptLevel Int = 0    , -- Change new item plus after upgrade
 @Old_CH_HA_ID Int  = 4265    , @New_CH_HA_ID Int  = 39022  ,    --@New 
 Chinese Sword
 @Old_CH_SA_ID Int = 4337    , @New_CH_SA_ID Int = 39025  ,    --@Chinese 
 Glaive
 @Old_CH_BA_ID Int  = 4373    , @New_CH_BA_ID Int  = 39028  ,    --@Chinese 
 Blade
 @Old_CH_LA_ID Int    = 4409    , @New_CH_LA_ID Int    = 39031  ,    --
 @Chinese Bow
 @Old_CH_AA_ID Int = 4445    , @New_CH_AA_ID Int    = 39034   ,    --
 @Chinese Shield
 @Old_EU_FA_ID Int = 4481    , @New_EU_FA_ID Int = 39037  ,    --@European 
 Dagger
 Update [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_Items] Set RefItemID = @New_CH_HA_ID  , 
 OptLevel = @NewOptLevel , CreaterName = @CreaterName Where ID64 = (Select           
 ItemID From [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_Inventory] Where CharID = @CharID and 
 Slot =      
 @WeaponSlot and ItemID> 0) and RefItemID = @Old_CH_HA_ID  and (OptLevel >= 
 @ReqOptLevel)    --@Sword
 Update [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_Items] Set RefItemID = @New_CH_BA_ID  , 
 OptLevel = @NewOptLevel , CreaterName = @CreaterName Where ID64 = (Select 
 ItemID From [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_Inventory] Where CharID = @CharID and 
 Slot = @WeaponSlot and ItemID> 0) and RefItemID = @Old_CH_BA_ID  and 
 (OptLevel >= @ReqOptLevel)    --@Blade
 Update [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_Items] Set RefItemID = @New_CH_SA_ID , 
 OptLevel = @NewOptLevel , CreaterName = @CreaterName Where ID64 = (Select 
 ItemID From [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_Inventory] Where CharID = @CharID and 
 Slot = @WeaponSlot and ItemID> 0) and RefItemID = @Old_CH_SA_ID and 
 (OptLevel >= @ReqOptLevel)    --@T-Blade
 Update [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_Items] Set RefItemID = @New_CH_LA_ID    , 
 OptLevel = @NewOptLevel , CreaterName = @CreaterName Where ID64 = (Select 
 ItemID From [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_Inventory] Where CharID = @CharID and 
 Slot = 
 @WeaponSlot and ItemID> 0) and RefItemID = @Old_CH_LA_ID    and (OptLevel 
 >= 
 @ReqOptLevel)    --@Bow
 Update [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_Items] Set RefItemID = @New_CH_AA_ID , 
 OptLevel = @NewOptLevel , CreaterName = @CreaterName Where ID64 = (Select 
 ItemID 
 From [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_Inventory] Where CharID = @CharID and Slot = 
 @WeaponSlot and ItemID> 0) and RefItemID = @Old_CH_AA_ID and (OptLevel >= 
 @ReqOptLevel)    --@Shield
 Update [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_Items] Set RefItemID = @New_EU_FA_ID , 
 OptLevel = @NewOptLevel , CreaterName = @CreaterName Where ID64 = (Select 
 ItemID 
 From [SRO_VT_SHARD].[dbo].[_Inventory] Where CharID = @CharID and Slot = 
 @WeaponSlot and ItemID> 0) and RefItemID = @Old_EU_FA_ID and (OptLevel >= 
 @ReqOptLevel)    --@Dagger
```

this 
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure _UpgradeSystemSETSUN, Line 24
    Incorrect syntax near '@Old_CH_HA_ID'.
 start from here

this sortcut from code

---

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure _UpgradeSystemSETSUN, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near '@Old_CH_HA_ID'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure _UpgradeSystemSETSUN, Line 126
Must declare the scalar variable "@New_CH_HA_ID".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure _UpgradeSystemSETSUN, Line 126
Must declare the scalar variable "@WeaponSlot".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure _UpgradeSystemSETSUN, Line 127
Must declare the scalar variable "@New_CH_BA_ID".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure _UpgradeSystemSETSUN, Line 127
Must declare the scalar variable "@WeaponSlot".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure _UpgradeSystemSETSUN, Line 128
...... more
```

Comment: How is this answerable without seeing the SQL that causes these errors?

Comment: Holy cow, can you do something about this wall of text?  Surely there's a way you can summarize it?

Comment: i cant but all code here its more than 50k

Comment: You need to provide a bit of context here. All you have shown is that you have declared some variables. Do you have a GO in the middle of your code somewhere. I would start with the syntax error and figure that out. And seriously....50k of code?

Comment: ok i will edit it sec

Comment: done or if u need all proc i can upload it for u

Comment: The code you posted does NOT produce the same error you stated in your question. You have several lines in this list of variables that are invalid. I really hope your real code does not look this horrendous. It is a nightmare to decipher this. Don't be scared to use some white space and multiple lines to avoid the wall of text.

Comment: `@New_EU_FA_ID Int = 39037  ,` ⇐ Remove the comma from the last declaration.

Comment: https://files.fm/u/zchzyyme   this full code

Comment: Remove that comma & it compiles

Comment: comma ?? where !

Comment: He showed you where....you have a comma after you declare the last variable.